C#: Json with Unicode character code and html Code decode in correct symbol/sign
I have a challenge to convert Unicode character code like /u009a into the correct sign (/u009a => š). Example: \u009a into š also i have html codes which need to be converted to the correct value like: &#263 => ć.
The language of my program is c# with framework net 8.
I get this values from a rest api as json response.
To make my question more clear here a example from the json properties what i get from the api which i need converted: Value: "lastname": "M\u00e1le\u009aevi&#263", "street": "Bauernfeldstra\u00dfe"
I need to convert the above Value into this c# properties: "lastname": "Málešović", "street": "Bauernfeldstraße"
This values saved into a Microsoft SQL Server where we generate reports with.
thank you

I don't get the examples in the first paragraph of your question \u009a is a special character "SCI" in unicode, 'š' would be \u0161.  Regarding the rest of the question. This seems to be a misunderstanding:  e.g.\u00df is exactly the same as 'ß', there is no conversion required.

Regarding having html encoded strings see HttpUtility.HtmlDecode

Read: How to decode a Unicode character in a string and How can I decode HTML characters in C#?

Decode of HTML Code works in my solution. Also the \u00df to ß. Only prolbem is \u009a to 'š' there is truggle and got nothing to work

@KlausGütter is there a way to get the valua \u0161 with \u009a. I need that for all special characters. When i convert 9a hex into decimal it is 154

Then it is not Unicode but probably  code page 1252.

@KlausGütter yea you are right it looks like Windows 1252. Is there a way to encode this to the correct sign?

So you say that the data you get is wrong. Is it possible to correct the problem  where it is created?
